# SVG SMIL path animation not working in Safari

Tags: svg, svg-animate, smil

I use SVG SMIL animation because I haven't found another way to animate a curved shape. This approach works perfectly for all browsers except for iOS browsers.

This is my SVG code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Слой_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 540 450" style="enable-background:new 0 0 540 450;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:rgba(115, 203, 232, 0.3);}
</style>
<path id="t" class="st0" d="M393.620000,413.170000C314.860000,451.100000,167.780000,449.910000,62.920000,346.580000C-41.940000,243.250000,16.830000,139.920000,106.710000,142.210000C196.590000,144.510000,248.440000,113.510000,292.230000,61.840000C336.020000,10.170000,425.890000,-12.790000,490.420000,67.580000C554.940000,147.960000,566.460000,329.930000,393.620000,413.170000Z;">
    <animate
        attributeName="d"
        attributeType="XML"
        dur="10s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="
            M393.620000,413.170000C314.860000,451.100000,167.780000,449.910000,62.920000,346.580000C-41.940000,243.250000,16.830000,139.920000,106.710000,142.210000C196.590000,144.510000,248.440000,113.510000,292.230000,61.840000C336.020000,10.170000,425.890000,-12.790000,490.420000,67.580000C554.940000,147.960000,566.460000,329.930000,393.620000,413.170000Z;
            M393.620000,413.170000C314.860000,451.100000,219.884470,381.470294,91.370310,296.084829C-59.166688,186.229543,29.222773,79.276069,119.102773,81.566069C208.982773,83.866069,254.758124,59.826606,334.437194,45.676998C441.848727,37.237015,431.408010,79.499494,495.938010,159.869494C560.458010,240.249494,566.460000,329.930000,393.620000,413.170000Z;
            M374.262300,334.744023C295.502300,372.674023,219.884470,464.784206,91.370310,379.398742C-59.166688,269.543456,86.027714,124.720021,175.907714,127.010021C265.787714,129.310021,254.758124,59.826606,334.437194,45.676998C441.848727,37.237015,434.437607,63.594111,498.967607,143.964111C563.487607,224.344111,547.102300,251.504023,374.262300,334.744023Z;
            M270,376.835237C191.240000,414.765237,181.548418,328.452349,53.034258,243.066884C-97.502740,133.211598,86.319021,36.861713,176.199021,39.151713C266.079021,41.451713,336.324192,10.071305,405.399674,50.570962C472.843833,113.093459,600.249772,160.249902,501.647635,230.831974C407.113801,294.083100,442.840000,293.595237,270,376.835237Z;
            M328.727569,304.241436C302.169852,351.959364,192.967667,434.488238,64.453507,349.102773C-86.083491,239.247487,100.185252,122.506085,163.148450,79.934747C247.318825,36.557748,311.038710,-14.398515,380.114192,26.101142C447.558351,88.623639,604.328075,280.967683,505.725938,351.549755C411.192104,414.800881,411.029233,229.973703,328.727569,304.241436Z;
            M393.620000,413.170000C314.860000,451.100000,167.780000,449.910000,62.920000,346.580000C-41.940000,243.250000,16.830000,139.920000,106.710000,142.210000C196.590000,144.510000,248.440000,113.510000,292.230000,61.840000C336.020000,10.170000,425.890000,-12.790000,490.420000,67.580000C554.940000,147.960000,566.460000,329.930000,393.620000,413.170000Z;
    "/>

</path>
<path id="t" class="st0" d="M281.180000,400.830000C201.970000,398.180000,84.420000,335.380000,43.820000,208.330000C3.230000,81.270000,93.960000,23.010000,165.130000,62.640000C236.310000,102.270000,291,99.180000,347.930000,76.100000C404.860000,53.020000,486.680000,72.370000,504.590000,164.030000C522.490000,255.690000,455.010000,406.660000,281.180000,400.830000Z">
    <animate
        attributeName="d"
        dur="10s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="
            M281.180000,400.830000C201.970000,398.180000,84.420000,335.380000,43.820000,208.330000C3.230000,81.270000,93.960000,23.010000,165.130000,62.640000C236.310000,102.270000,291,99.180000,347.930000,76.100000C404.860000,53.020000,486.680000,72.370000,504.590000,164.030000C522.490000,255.690000,455.010000,406.660000,281.180000,400.830000Z;
            M314.232437,343.451865C235.022437,340.801865,68.622550,431.473244,28.022550,304.423244C-12.567450,177.363244,80.443183,65.747277,145.108413,88.464874C255.317034,138.502506,258.603391,56.904805,315.533391,33.824805C372.463391,10.744805,486.680000,72.370000,504.590000,164.030000C522.490000,255.690000,488.062437,349.281865,314.232437,343.451865Z;
            M284.310494,403.295750C205.100494,400.645750,119.359757,400.250347,78.759757,273.200347C38.169757,146.140347,137.685161,85.261587,188.039896,57.241977C302.151379,35.727137,344.466357,155.777310,381.882047,136.600173C446.617771,113.520173,551.309427,137.307909,523.686036,212.055507C467.431656,320.627909,458.140494,409.125750,284.310494,403.295750Z;
            M283.009540,355.160451C119.237528,330.394232,92.039722,396.347485,51.439722,269.297485C10.849722,142.237485,60.928873,8.505299,120.390286,55.941023C256.617988,143.706323,233.885264,158.379218,288.213356,167.823070C367.259574,178.567875,462.844553,181.540346,435.221162,256.287944C378.966782,364.860346,456.839540,360.990451,283.009540,355.160451Z;
            M307.727667,404.596704C149.159471,399.344795,63.418734,479.608543,22.818734,352.558543C-17.771266,225.498543,127.277529,224.463669,173.729402,166.522116C278.734207,50.037633,336.660633,79.021023,361.066782,102.775369C416.695828,196.781232,491.465542,207.559427,485.958369,299.219428C479.140242,367.462255,481.557667,410.426704,307.727667,404.596704Z;
            M281.180000,400.830000C201.970000,398.180000,84.420000,335.380000,43.820000,208.330000C3.230000,81.270000,93.960000,23.010000,165.130000,62.640000C236.310000,102.270000,291,99.180000,347.930000,76.100000C404.860000,53.020000,486.680000,72.370000,504.590000,164.030000C522.490000,255.690000,455.010000,406.660000,281.180000,400.830000Z;
    "/>

</path>

</svg>
```

I noticed that in Safari and other iOS browsers animation works if the `attributeName` attribute has a different value, such as `fill` for example. But I need to work with `arrtributeName = 'd'` since it is about changing the form.

Please tell me how I can fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon at the end of the last paths for the `values`. You also have extra semicolons at the end of the `d` attributes

```css
svg{width:300px; border:solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 540 450" >
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:rgba(115, 203, 232, 0.3);}
</style>
<path class="st0" d="M393.620000,413.170000C314.860000,451.100000,167.780000,449.910000,62.920000,346.580000C-41.940000,243.250000,16.830000,139.920000,106.710000,142.210000C196.590000,144.510000,248.440000,113.510000,292.230000,61.840000C336.020000,10.170000,425.890000,-12.790000,490.420000,67.580000C554.940000,147.960000,566.460000,329.930000,393.620000,413.170000Z">
    <animate
        attributeType="XML"
        attributeName='d'
        dur="10s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="
            M393.620000,413.170000C314.860000,451.100000,167.780000,449.910000,62.920000,346.580000C-41.940000,243.250000,16.830000,139.920000,106.710000,142.210000C196.590000,144.510000,248.440000,113.510000,292.230000,61.840000C336.020000,10.170000,425.890000,-12.790000,490.420000,67.580000C554.940000,147.960000,566.460000,329.930000,393.620000,413.170000Z;
                
            M393.620000,413.170000C314.860000,451.100000,219.884470,381.470294,91.370310,296.084829C-59.166688,186.229543,29.222773,79.276069,119.102773,81.566069C208.982773,83.866069,254.758124,59.826606,334.437194,45.676998C441.848727,37.237015,431.408010,79.499494,495.938010,159.869494C560.458010,240.249494,566.460000,329.930000,393.620000,413.170000Z;
                
            M374.262300,334.744023C295.502300,372.674023,219.884470,464.784206,91.370310,379.398742C-59.166688,269.543456,86.027714,124.720021,175.907714,127.010021C265.787714,129.310021,254.758124,59.826606,334.437194,45.676998C441.848727,37.237015,434.437607,63.594111,498.967607,143.964111C563.487607,224.344111,547.102300,251.504023,374.262300,334.744023Z;
                
            M270,376.835237C191.240000,414.765237,181.548418,328.452349,53.034258,243.066884C-97.502740,133.211598,86.319021,36.861713,176.199021,39.151713C266.079021,41.451713,336.324192,10.071305,405.399674,50.570962C472.843833,113.093459,600.249772,160.249902,501.647635,230.831974C407.113801,294.083100,442.840000,293.595237,270,376.835237Z;
                
            M328.727569,304.241436C302.169852,351.959364,192.967667,434.488238,64.453507,349.102773C-86.083491,239.247487,100.185252,122.506085,163.148450,79.934747C247.318825,36.557748,311.038710,-14.398515,380.114192,26.101142C447.558351,88.623639,604.328075,280.967683,505.725938,351.549755C411.192104,414.800881,411.029233,229.973703,328.727569,304.241436Z;
                
            M393.620000,413.170000C314.860000,451.100000,167.780000,449.910000,62.920000,346.580000C-41.940000,243.250000,16.830000,139.920000,106.710000,142.210000C196.590000,144.510000,248.440000,113.510000,292.230000,61.840000C336.020000,10.170000,425.890000,-12.790000,490.420000,67.580000C554.940000,147.960000,566.460000,329.930000,393.620000,413.170000Z"/>

</path>
<path  class="st0" d="M281.180000,400.830000C201.970000,398.180000,84.420000,335.380000,43.820000,208.330000C3.230000,81.270000,93.960000,23.010000,165.130000,62.640000C236.310000,102.270000,291,99.180000,347.930000,76.100000C404.860000,53.020000,486.680000,72.370000,504.590000,164.030000C522.490000,255.690000,455.010000,406.660000,281.180000,400.830000Z">
    <animate
        attributeName="d"
        dur="10s"
        repeatCount="indefinite"
        values="
            M281.180000,400.830000C201.970000,398.180000,84.420000,335.380000,43.820000,208.330000C3.230000,81.270000,93.960000,23.010000,165.130000,62.640000C236.310000,102.270000,291,99.180000,347.930000,76.100000C404.860000,53.020000,486.680000,72.370000,504.590000,164.030000C522.490000,255.690000,455.010000,406.660000,281.180000,400.830000Z;
            M314.232437,343.451865C235.022437,340.801865,68.622550,431.473244,28.022550,304.423244C-12.567450,177.363244,80.443183,65.747277,145.108413,88.464874C255.317034,138.502506,258.603391,56.904805,315.533391,33.824805C372.463391,10.744805,486.680000,72.370000,504.590000,164.030000C522.490000,255.690000,488.062437,349.281865,314.232437,343.451865Z;
            M284.310494,403.295750C205.100494,400.645750,119.359757,400.250347,78.759757,273.200347C38.169757,146.140347,137.685161,85.261587,188.039896,57.241977C302.151379,35.727137,344.466357,155.777310,381.882047,136.600173C446.617771,113.520173,551.309427,137.307909,523.686036,212.055507C467.431656,320.627909,458.140494,409.125750,284.310494,403.295750Z;
            M283.009540,355.160451C119.237528,330.394232,92.039722,396.347485,51.439722,269.297485C10.849722,142.237485,60.928873,8.505299,120.390286,55.941023C256.617988,143.706323,233.885264,158.379218,288.213356,167.823070C367.259574,178.567875,462.844553,181.540346,435.221162,256.287944C378.966782,364.860346,456.839540,360.990451,283.009540,355.160451Z;
            M307.727667,404.596704C149.159471,399.344795,63.418734,479.608543,22.818734,352.558543C-17.771266,225.498543,127.277529,224.463669,173.729402,166.522116C278.734207,50.037633,336.660633,79.021023,361.066782,102.775369C416.695828,196.781232,491.465542,207.559427,485.958369,299.219428C479.140242,367.462255,481.557667,410.426704,307.727667,404.596704Z;
            M281.180000,400.830000C201.970000,398.180000,84.420000,335.380000,43.820000,208.330000C3.230000,81.270000,93.960000,23.010000,165.130000,62.640000C236.310000,102.270000,291,99.180000,347.930000,76.100000C404.860000,53.020000,486.680000,72.370000,504.590000,164.030000C522.490000,255.690000,455.010000,406.660000,281.180000,400.830000Z"/>

</path>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, your advice helped, but not just because of the semicolon. I also noticed that in order for the animation to work correctly in Safari, I needed to change the value of "viewBox", but I still didn't understand why or what the problem was. I also needed to get rid of all closing </animate> tags. This doesn't apply to this example, but I've had other similar animations.

Comment: I've changed the viewBox in order to make the shapes fit inside the svg canvas. In order to know the values to use for the `viewBox` I've wrapped the shapes  in a <g> element and I've used the getBBox() method to get the bounding box of the <g> (the smallest rectangle in which the group fits): theGroup.getBBox().

This is returning an SVGRect object with the following properties: x, y, width, height. You can use those properties to build the value for the viewBox attribute: viewBox = "x y width height"

Comment: Also I see that you have a repeated id="t". Please mage sure you don't have repeated `id`s